# Weird behavior in ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this piece of code which works perfectly fine if I set a break point at code behind and let the value become zero and continue to run the rest of the code.

However it will break if i did not set a break point and let it run and the value will become 2 and break.

Does anyone have any idea why? The AJAX code below triggers when the user enters something in the textbox.

```
function getmachineinfo(serial) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("actionname", "controller")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { "serial": serial },
        success: function (data) {alert('success')}, error: function (err) {
            alert(err)
        }}
```

```chsarp
public JsonResult getmachine(string serial)
{

    var machine= service.GetWarrantyDetailsBySerial(serial);     
    result.AccessoriesWs = new List<AccessoriesW>();

    //set break point here and let the result.AccessoriesW to be re declared and set to 0 and it will works.if i don set break point.result.AccessoriesW  will not have enough time to reset to zero.

    return Json(machine, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Javascript error**

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type

**Result is parent object and AccessoriesW is child object** resetting the child object will not get any errors.

**Update solution**

instead of using

`result.AccessoriesWs = new List<AccessoriesW>();`

i change it to below and problem solved. i think re declaring constructor is too slow for ajax.

```
   result.JuraAccessoriesWs.Clear();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the `GetWarrantyDetailsBySerial()` method asynchronous?

Comment: @Rory it is not asynchronous.
@ZakariaAcharki . The problem is the code run too fast. No time for `result.AccessoriesWs = new List<AccessoriesW>();` to reset this line. resulting it to bring the value to front end and cause error.

Comment: `The problem is the code run too fast. No time for result.AccessoriesWs = new List<AccessoriesW>(); to reset this line.` That's just not possible. There must be another underlying problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But if i set a break point after that line. it will works fine when i see the Accessories become zero and continue

Comment: What do you mean by 'become zero'? It's a `List<>`....

Comment: i am resetting the `List<AccessoriesW>()` Count to zero with new constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result looks like an instance (not local) variable... It is probably being overridden by other calls in the same controller? Do you do other AJAX calls at the same time?

It is noting to do with timing, you should either construct the result object locally so it cannot be changed by other code during the action.

Comment: i do have 2 ajax but calling different controller.That's y i am finding it weird also. Another possible reason is my javascript event. causing it to call multiple times. `$("#Q_Serial").on('keyup paste', function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
           
           var artno = $("#Q_Serial").val();
                if (artno.length==14) {
                    getmachineinfo(artno);
                }

        });`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i thinkthe answer is really javascript event causing the problem.

```
$("#Q_Serial").on('keyup paste', function (e) { var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); var artno = $("#Q_Serial").val(); if (artno.length==14) { getmachineinfo(artno); } });
```

keyup and paste both trigger the ajax at the same time.removing the 'paste' solved the issue as well.Thanks Milney for helping me to make it clear for me. Or else i am stuck with stupid solution above.